# how to apply FOR LOOP for the two different data

Tags: python, numpy

This my data

```
data1 = [0, 1.12, 0.96]
data2 = [0.96, 0, 0]
data3 = [0, 1.2, 1.28]

length_T_bd = 220 #Newton
length_T_be = 250 #Newton
length_r_bd = 0
r_d = np.array(data1)
r_b = np.array(data2)
r_e = np.array(data3)
```

calculations

```
r_bd = r_b - r_d
r_be = r_b - r_e

for value in r_bd:
    length_r_bd += value ** 2
    length_r_bd = np.sqrt(length_r_bd)
    u_bd = r_bd / length_r_bd
    T_bd = length_T_bd * u_bd
```

I can obtain T_bd as it is seen above. Also, i want to obtain T_be by the same procedure. However i need to use FOR LOOP two times to do this.

Is there any option to make it more wisely.

Answer (score -1):

This only works if r_bd and r_be have the same length:

```
r_bd = r_b - r_d
r_be = r_b - r_e

for value_bd, value_be in zip(r_bd, r_be):
  length_r_bd += value_bd ** 2
  length_r_bd = np.sqrt(length_r_bd)
  u_bd = r_bd / length_r_bd
  T_bd = length_T_bd * u_bd

  length_r_be += value_be ** 2
  length_r_be = np.sqrt(length_r_be)
  u_be = r_be / length_r_be
  T_be = length_T_be * u_be
```

Comment: yes, they have same length. It worked, but results not true.

Comment: It will actually work if they have different lengths but it will only take into account the the first `min(len(r_bd), len(r_be))` elements.

Comment: @fbezir, what result did you expect and what did you get? For T_bd I see the same

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you want to apply the same processing to a number of different inputs. What you need  here is a function. Also it seems you overwrite a number of your variables so:

```
def do_calc(ar, length_T):
    length_r = np.sqrt(ar ** 2) # This is where the 'iteration' happens
    u = ar / length_r
    T = length_T * u
    return T

T_bd = do_cal(r_bd, length_T_bd)
T_be = do_cal(r_be, lenght_T_be)
```